# OpenVPN client for kubernetes azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, openvpn, azure-appservice

I have an azure app service running. I need to use the functions in this app servie from the kubernetes pod which have an API to call the function in App service. The app service has restrictions.
I have tried giving access to  IP of pod by whitelisting it in app service but unable to access .Can we set a VPN in the pod which can allow the access to azure App service. I am new to kubernetes please mention the ways to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi @user14856694, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you use the Azure Arc environment in AKS for accessing the app service deployed in a pod in AKS. Through Azure Arc enabled AKS, you will be able to enable threat protection and apply policy definitions effectively. To deploy the Azure Arc, you will need to install the Azure CLI extensions as given below and connect the AKS cluster to Azure Arc. Then deploy the log analytics workspace in the same resource group to monitor and log the activity of the applications deployed on the AKS cluster. Then install the required app service extensions in the Azure Arc and create a custom location in Azure to assign the App Service Kubernetes environment.

•   Once done, you will have to create an App Service Kubernetes environment and then create your app service in it in the custom location as defined earlier. Then, you can deploy your required application code in the app service already created. In this way, you can deploy an app service in AKS cluster using the Arc extension resource which helps in restricting the pod communication through allowed IP addresses and restricted IP addresses.

•   For more details, kindly refer to the link below which describes in detail the deployment of Azure Arc in AKS cluster: -

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/app-service-on-kubernetes-with-azure-arc/ba-p/2867959